# what is wrong with this simple regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am stuck in a dump:

```
import re
print re.search('return[^$]+',
                'return to the Treasury of $40 million\nnow!').group(0)
```

The above regex only prints `return to the Treasury of`, but I expected it to include `$40 million`.  What I understand from regex is that I am asking it to `take every thing until the end of the line`.

I do not want to use `.*`, I want `endline delimiter` to go until the end of line from some point.  If I remove $ from search string it prints the full string.  Why is endline delimiter matching with dollar sign??

Comment: Have you actually tested `return.+` or `return.+$` as regex patterns? Because it sounds like those will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return[^$]+
```

will match a string "return" followed by any character that is not '$' one or more times.

This is because [ ] mean character group and inside [ ] the special characters are threaded as simple characters.

Thus it matches only until the the dollar sign.

Why not use:

```
return.+$
```

this is exactly what you want.

Comment: ok i understand this, how i tell regex to use `$` in `charater class []` to interpret it as `end line delimiter` but not as `dollar character`, as we  also use `[^\d+]` here we are telling the regix to go until any digit, why it is not interpreting `d` as 'alphabet d' then? if i use `[^\$]+` regex still interpret `$` as character :s

Comment: Only if re.MULTILINE is also used, otherwise $ means end-of-string.

Comment: `.+$` seems to be also working, but i have used `[\s\S]+$` which is good to, thanks indeed

Comment: [\s\S] is exactly the same as .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use `.*`?

The regex you have will match any string that starts with "return", then one or more characters that are not the "$" character. Note that this will NOT look for the end-of-line marker.

`return.*$` will match everything up to and including the end of line marker. You may (but probably not) need to make the `.*` a lazy matcher if you are dealing with multi-line input.

Comment: i do not want to use `.*` because my string is multiline i can use `[\s\S]+?` but i do not know where to stop. e.g. if you use this regex `return[\s\S]+?` on above string it will only print return

Comment: @Aamir - Try it without the `?`.

Comment: $ will only match end-of-line if re.MULTILINE is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = 'we will return to the Treasury of $40 million\nunits of money.'
re.search(r'return.*$', text, re.MULTILINE).group(0)

# prints 'we will return to the Treasury of $40 million'
```

You need to include the multiline flag, then $ will match at newlines.